# Annotation ManyToMany unique key issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm facing an issue with hibernate :

I have two class collaborator and collaboration and I want a **ManyToMany** relation between them.

My Collaborator class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Collaborateur")
public class Collaborateur {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private Integer id;
    private String lastname;
    private String firstname;
    private String email;
```

And my collaboration class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Collaboration")
public class Collaboration {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private Integer id;

    private String nameCollaboration;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Collaborator.class ,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Collaborator> collaborators;
```

When I insert twice the same collaborator in the list collaboration I have the following error :

> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement

Or more precisely :

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry '2' for key 'UK_obmdv02oey7264a085m7baqbo'

In fact, it's saying that I can't assign for a collaborator two differents collaborations.

So I printed the creation of the table created by mysql for the n-n relation and I have this :

```
CREATE TABLE `Collaboration_Collaborator` (
  `Collaboration_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `collaborators_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_obmdv02oey7264a085m7baqbo` (`collaborators_id`),
  KEY `FKlrsiogs304faydykt1xtgpk9k` (`Collaboration_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So I need to specify that my unique key is not only collaborators_id but both collaborators_id and collaboration_id.

How can I proceed ?

Comment: Collaborator is different from Collaborateur?

Comment: Did you find the answer for your question?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add jointable annotation

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity=Collaborator.class ,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable
private List<Collaborator> collaborators;
```

Answer (score 0):

To put additional information of Amer's answer:

## SQL

As per your definition, you put an `UNIQUE` constraint on `collaborators_id` only in your `Collaboration_Collaborator` table. You need to extend the constraint to both columns. [It's usually written like](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp):

```
CONSTRAINT "UK_obmdv02oey7264a085m7baqbo" UNIQUE(Collaboration_id, collaborators_id)
```

Please check the correct syntax suiting your database

## JPA

As Amer's mentioned, you'll need the `@JoinTable` annotation. By the way, you can drop the `targetEntity`:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(schema = "myschema", name = "Collaboration_Collaborator",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "Collaboration_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "collaborators_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private List<Collaborator> collaborators;
```

Some points:

1. `schema` is optional but I like to put it to avoid confusion
2. please notice the order of `joinColumns` and `inverseJoinColumns`: `joinColumns` refers to the current entity (`Collaboration` in your case) and `inverseJoinColumns` refers to the the entity `Collaboration` is related to
3. I assumed that in tables `Collaboration` and `Collaborateur`, primary key columns are `id`

## Misc

As per best practices, please avoid mixing languages: "Collaborator" (English) and "Collaborateur" (assuming French)

Answer (score 0):

Use this join table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Collaboration_Collaborator` (
    `Collaboration_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `collaborators_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY `UK_obmdv02oey7264a085m7baqbo` (`collaborators_id`, `Collaboration_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```